# Switch viewController on device orentation in ios xcode Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, orientation, device

I want to change viewController view on device orientation.
having two screens.
1. which is designed in portrait mode.
2. Another is designed in Landscape mode.

above both the screen is loginScreen, but having a different view.So, I want to change screenView accordingly device orientation Objective - c

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Size Classes to achieve your functionality.

Refer to the following links :

http://www.hossamghareeb.com/size-classes-tutorial/
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Size_Classes_to_Design_Adaptable_Universal_iOS_9_User_Interfaces